# What is the rationale for only marking certain letters with sheva, when they are the last letter in a word?

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, writing-printing, vowels-nekudot

In printed and manuscript editions of Tanach, I've noticed that a *sheva* on the final letter of a word is almost never marked, and is meant to be inferred.

The two exceptions I've come across are:

1. A final *chaf* e.g.

[Bereishit 1:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0101.htm) (among very many):

> וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָֽיְתָ֥ה תֹ֨הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ **וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ** עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְה֑וֹם וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃‏

2. A plosive letter e.g.

[Bamidbar 21:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0421.htm):

> וַיִּשְׁמַ֞ע הַכְּנַֽעֲנִ֤י מֶֽלֶךְ־עֲרָד֙ יֹשֵׁ֣ב הַנֶּ֔גֶב כִּ֚י בָּ֣א יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל דֶּ֖רֶךְ הָֽאֲתָרִ֑ים וַיִּלָּ֨חֶם֙ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל **וַיִּ֥שְׁבְּ** ׀ מִמֶּ֖נּוּ שֶֽׁבִי׃‏

[Shemot 18:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0218.htm):

> **וַיִּ֣חַדְּ** יִתְר֔וֹ עַ֚ל כָּל־הַטּוֹבָ֔ה אֲשֶׁר־עָשָׂ֥ה יְהוָ֖ה לְיִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל אֲשֶׁ֥ר הִצִּיל֖וֹ מִיַּ֥ד מִצְרָֽיִם׃‏

[Mishlei 22:21](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c2822.htm):

> לְהוֹדִֽיעֲךָ֗ **קֹ֭שְׁטְ** אִמְרֵ֣י אֱמֶ֑ת    לְהָשִׁ֥יב אֲמָרִ֥ים אֱ֝מֶ֗ת לְשֹֽׁלְחֶֽיךָ׃‏

[Bereishit 29:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0129.htm):

> וַיִּשַּׁ֥ק יַֽעֲקֹ֖ב לְרָחֵ֑ל וַיִּשָּׂ֥א אֶת־קֹל֖וֹ **וַיֵּֽבְךְּ**׃‏

[Mishlei 30:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c2830.htm):

> אַל־**תּ֥וֹסְףְּ** עַל־דְּבָרָ֑יו פֶּן־יוֹכִ֖יחַ בְּךָ֣ וְנִכְזָֽבְתָּ׃‏

[Shemot 2:17](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0202.htm):

> וַיָּבֹ֥אוּ הָֽרֹעִ֖ים וַיְגָֽרְשׁ֑וּם וַיָּ֤קָם מֹשֶׁה֙ וַיּ֣וֹשִׁעָ֔ן **וַיַּ֖שְׁקְ** אֶת־צֹאנָֽם׃‏

[Bereishit 12:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0112.htm) (among many):

> וַיְהִ֕י כַּֽאֲשֶׁ֥ר הִקְרִ֖יב לָב֣וֹא מִצְרָ֑יְמָה וַיֹּ֨אמֶר֙ אֶל־שָׂרַ֣י אִשְׁתּ֔וֹ הִנֵּה־נָ֣א יָדַ֔עְתִּי כִּ֛י אִשָּׁ֥ה יְפַת־מַרְאֶ֖ה **אָֽתְּ**׃‏

What is different about these cases that means that the *sheva* is marked?

Comment: In the latter case,the shva is arguably na'. Only a shva nach is customarily omitted (hence the common name of the phenomenon "nach nistar")

Comment: I have a vague recollection of seeing a final _mem_ (at the end of a word) with a _sh'va_ printed, somewhere in _Tanach_. I could be misremembering (and I've no idea what that would mean different from a regular final _mem_, anyway).

Comment: @msh perhaps thinking of https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%92 where the printer had the vowels over the ktiv or something like that?

Comment: @DoubleAA Why would the sheva in ויחד or את be na’?

Comment: https://leshoniada.co.il/2020/05/24/%D7%A6%D6%B8%D7%A8%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B0-%D7%A0%D6%B5%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B0-%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B4%D7%9C%D6%B7%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B0-%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94/

Comment: https://faculty.biu.ac.il/~ofery/papers/sva%20bsof%20amila%20bnekod%20atvaruany.pdf